# Django filter() Query giving extra result in data

Tags: python, django, orm, django-orm

I have 2 objects `contacts`, `companies_contact`, I am using distinct() to get distinct value from contact

the code looks like this:

```
contacts = Contact.objects.filter(campaign=campaign)

companies_contacts = contacts.distinct('website')
```

So, when I iterate the `companies_contact` I'm getting the following output...

```
>>>for i in companies_contacts:
       i.created_at, i.website

(datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 9, 10, 57, 40, 447445, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'www.creamstone.com')
(datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 19, 6, 27, 32, 758898, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'www.facebook.com')
(datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 18, 6, 20, 41, 145358, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'www.heteja.com')
(datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 9, 12, 11, 17, 390755, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'www.kfc .com')
(datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 31, 6, 44, 40, 916231, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'www.mvg.com')
(datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 11, 12, 20, 55, 409986, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'www.subway.com')
(datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 9, 9, 14, 58, 607180, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'www.websit.com')
(datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 9, 6, 29, 53, 270203, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'www.website.com')
(datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 9, 9, 22, 22, 869395, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'www.websitest.com')
```

So, according to my understating `companies_contact` consists of this much data only but when I'm applying `filter()` on `companies_contact` with the different date which is not in above output then also it gives me the result.

```
companies_contacts.filter(created_at__startswith='2018-02-01')
```

The above query giving me the result but this `created_at` value is not there when I have iterate `companies_contact`

I don't know why it is giving result and why it is working but **I don't want result if the dates are not there**.

[image]

Comment: Sinice you write `distinct('website')` it is possible that in the first query, you simply ignored those rows.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I used ```distinct('website')``` because after getting distinct data I need to get information from different dates from only those data set not from ignored rows.

Comment: Well then you should use `distinct('website')` in the second query as well..

Comment: ok.. then it will never give me the proper data according to the implementation. This iteration and filter query I have used in the different function and distinct in different function. So, I'm passing the distinct object to other function for iteration. So, is there any good way to implement?
thanks in advance... :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do, so I'm guessing that maybe is because of the **startswith** tag inside the of the filter. What if you change startswith tag with gte and lt:
1. Parse '2018-02-01' to datetime object.

```
date_obj = parse('2018-02-01')
```

2. Filter with greater than equal and less than.

```
companies_contacts.filter(
     created_at__gte=date_obj,
     created_at__lt=date_obj + relativedelta(days=+1)
)
```

I'm using dateutil package:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
```